# Sum of the series $1+\frac{1\cdot 3}{6}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{6\cdot8}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Decide if the sum of the series
$$1+\frac{1\cdot3}{6}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{6\cdot8}+ \cdots$$
is: (i) $\infty$, (ii) $1$, (iii) $2$, (iv) $4$.

Comment: $1.3.5=1\times3\times5$ ...?

Comment: Well, it's certainly more than $1$ :P

Comment: yes.obviously...

Comment: the pattern here is not quite obvious yet

Comment: @chabuk are you multiplying "yes" and "obviously" right now? :)

Comment: What's the next term?

Comment: A pattern in our terms appears to emerge:$$1,\frac36,\frac36\cdot\frac58,\dots$$so I think the general $n$-th term of our series is given by $\large\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{2k+1}{2k+4}$ for $n\ge0$. As $2k+1=2k+4-3$ we have:$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac3{2k+4}\right)$$Can we simplify this further? This is about as far as I know to do. edit: judging by how Wolfram Alpha reduces the above product it appears rewriting in terms of the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Calculating_products) may be useful

Comment: The sum is $4$ according to Mathematica

Comment: I think the terms decrease by a factor of $(2k+1)/(2k+4)$ each time.

Comment: @Potato see my answer below. this series converges rather slowly :-o

Comment: @HenrySwanson $\infty,1,2,4$ are not partial sums, they are answer options for the infinite series

Comment: Ah, did not read then. Whoops.

Comment: @Cocopuffs [are you a physicist](http://www.smbc-comics.com/comics/20130120.gif) by any chance :)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom This one might go on my door collection

Comment: I have a proof, but it uses Mathematica to get an otherwise unobtainable insight. I'll post it if no one else can find something. Essentially, you can reduce the form RecklessReckoner gives below to the power series of ${2k+1\choose k+2}x^k$ integrated once with $1/2$ plugged in (up to a constant). Wolfram Alpha can find a closed form for this, but it's a messy quotient of square roots that you would never find by hand in a thousand years.

Comment: Haha, I don't feel so bad now:  I was wondering if there was any way to compute the _actual_ convergent sum...

Comment: @RecklessReckoner There ought to be an easier way. After all, whoever posed this question was able to find the sum.

Comment: Fair enough!  Although there's nothing that says the _poser_ didn't find the sum as **Cocopuffs** did, and then make up the "distractor" multiple choices... ;)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner That's true. But look at the series. It's quite simple. I would be very sad there was not an easier way.

Comment: You're right, of course.  I'm not expert enough to say _how_ to evaluate the sum, though I'm wondering if it's a piece out of a non-elementary function, the values for which are well-known (I'm studying Bessel functions at the moment and I can tell you it's not one of them.)... Why not go ahead and post what you found?  It might spawn an idea from someone else.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Wolfram is able to give a formula for the partial sums, presumably using the hockey stick identity. One can then compute the limit of the partial sums using this closed form with Stirling's formula. I still find this unsatisfactory though. There must a simpler way.

Comment: Oh, I think you just use the binomial theorem with $1/2$ as the exponent. Ugh. Too late for math.

Comment: @Potato: Seeing this comemnt only now. Indeed that was it.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thanks for writing it up.

Comment: Should the tag not be [tag:sequences-and-series] instead of [tag:number-theory]?

Answer (score 11):

> O [method of differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), so powerful and yet so despised...

The $n$th term of the series to be computed is
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k+1}{2k+4}=\frac4{2n+4}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k+1}{2k+2}=4(1-a_{n+1})\prod_{k=1}^na_k
$$ where $$a_k=\frac{2k+1}{2k+2}$$
By telescoping, each partial sum of the series is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k+1}{2k+4}=4-4\prod_{k=1}^Na_k
$$
Since $1-a_k\sim1/(2k)$, the product $\prod\limits_na_n$ diverges to $0$ hence the sum of the full series is $4$.

> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k+1}{2k+4}=4
> $$

More generally, for every $(a,b)$ such that $a>-1$ and $b>a+1$, 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k+a}{k+b}=\frac{b}{b-a-1}\left(1-\prod_{k=1}^Na_k\right)$$ where $$a_k=\frac{k+a}{k+b-1}$$
hence, if furthermore $b\leqslant 2+a$, then the product $\prod\limits_na_n$ diverges to $0$ hence

> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k+a}{k+b}=\frac{b}{b-a-1}$$

The question above asks about the case $$a=1/2\qquad b=2$$ which fits these conditions.

**Edit:** Another exact formula for the partial sums, equivalent to the one above, is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k+1}{2k+4}=4-4\cdot\frac1{4^N}{2N+1\choose N}
$$

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand... what do you mean by "by concatenation"? That is, from $\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k+1}{2k+4} = 4(1-a_{n+1})\prod_{k=1}^na_k$, how do you get $\sum_{n=0}^N\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k+1}{2k+4}=4-4\prod_{k=1}^{N+1}a_k$ in one step? (BTW, by "diverges to $0$", I guess you mean "converges to $0$"? :-))

Comment: Concatenation refers to cancellations. Let me suggest you compute $\sum\limits_{n=0}^3(1-a_{n+1})\prod\limits_{k=1}^na_k$ and see the miracle happen. // By "diverges to 0" I mean... "diverges to 0". Infinite products of positive terms such that the sequence of partial products converges to 0 are said to diverge to 0 (by opposition to those converging to a finite positive limit).

Comment: @Did But $0$ is finite. So shouldn't it be "converges"? I thought "diverges" is used only when the limit of a sequence doesn't exist.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar: an infinite product is said to diverge if its partial products tend to $0$ (or $\infty$). Think of the log of an infinite product as the infinite sum of logs. The product diverges to $0$ when the sum of the logs diverges to $-\infty$.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks for the info. I didn't know that.

Comment: @Did: Thanks. I just woke up, and came here to say I see it now! I usually see this phenomenon under the name "telescoping"; I hadn't heard the name "concatenation" before. Actually if I had seen $4(1-a_{n+1})\prod_{k=1}^na_k$ written as $4\prod_{k=1}^na_k - 4\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}a_k$ I'd have seen it instantly; somehow last night when I posted the comment I didn't make the connection, and thought "concatenation" was some new method I should be aware of. Thanks again, this is very nice.

Comment: Telescoping is better (somehow I keep forgetting the name).

Answer (score 11):

As suggested in another answer, one can write:

$$\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k+1}{2k+4}=\frac{8}{\pi}\cdot \frac{\Gamma (n+\frac{3}{2})\Gamma (\frac{3}{2})}{\Gamma (n+3)}=\frac{8}{\pi}\text{B}\left(n+\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)$$

Now, using the definition of the beta function, our sum is:

$$1+\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_0^1 t^{n+\frac{1}{2}}(1-t)^{\frac{1}{2}}\,dt=1+\frac{8}{\pi}\int_0^1 t^{\frac{3}{2}}(1-t)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\,dt$$

Letting $t=\sin^2 w,$ this gives

$$1+\frac{16}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^4 w\,dw=1+\frac{16}{\pi}\left(\frac{3\pi}{16}\right)=4$$

Answer (score 9):

Note that
$$\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-r+1)}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots r}$$
and so
$$\binom{1/2}{r} = \frac{\frac12 \cdot \frac{-1}2 \cdot \frac{-3}{2} \cdot \frac{-5}{2} \cdots \frac{-(2r-3)}{2}}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots r} = \frac{(-1)^{r-1}1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2r-3)}{2^r r!}$$

Now, in this problem, each term after the "$1$" term follows a pattern. Let the last factor in the denominator of a term be $2r$, then the general term is:
$$
\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2r - 3)}{6 \cdot 8 \cdot 10 \cdots (2r)}
= \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2r - 3)}{2^{r-2} 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdots r}
= \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2r - 3)}{2^{r-3} r!}
= 8 (-1)^{r-1} \binom{1/2}{r} \\
= -8\binom{1/2}{r}(-1)^r
$$

We know from the binomial theorem that $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{r} x^r = (1 + x)^n$ for $|x| < 1$, and with $x = -1$, we also know that for positive integer $n$, at least, we have $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r = (1-1)^n = 0$. In light of these, it is not hard to believe that $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{r} (-1)^r = 0$ as well: I'm not exactly sure how to prove this, but it would follow from a [Tauberian theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_and_tauberian_theorems) considering we can prove that the sum converges.

So our sum in this problem is
$$
1 + \sum_{r=3}^{\infty} -8 \binom{1/2}{r} (-1)^r 
= 1 - 8\sum_{r=3}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{r} (-1)^r 
$$

The sum inside is almost the sum we said above is $0$, except that the $r = 0, 1, 2$ terms are missing. In other words, our sum in this problem is:

$$
\begin{align}
&1 - 8\Bigg(0 - \Big(1 + \frac12(-1) + \frac{(1/2)(-1/2)}{2}\Big)\Bigg) \\
&= 1 + 8\left(\frac38\right) \\
&= 4.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: [Abel's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) should be useful in showing that $\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{r}(-1)^r=0$

Answer (score 8):

The series can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{align}
&1+\frac{1\cdot3}{6}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{6\cdot8}+\dots\\
&8\left(\frac1{2\cdot4}+\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot4\cdot6}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8}+\dots\right)\\
&=8\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k+2)!!}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
This is reminiscent of the series (obtained by the binomial theorem)
$$
\begin{align}
(1-x)^{-1/2}
&=1+\frac12x+\frac12\frac32\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac12\frac32\frac52\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}x^k\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Substitute $x\mapsto x^2$ and multiply by $x$ to get
$$
x(1-x^2)^{-1/2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}x^{2k+1}\tag{3}
$$
Integration yields
$$
1-\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k+2)!!}x^{2k+2}\tag{4}
$$
Plugging in $x=1$ and subtracting $\frac12=\frac{(-1)!!}{2!!}$ yields
$$
\frac12=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k+2)!!}\tag{5}
$$
Multiplying by $8$ and applying $(1)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
4
&=8\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k+2)!!}\\
&=1+\frac{1\cdot3}{6}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{6\cdot8}+\dots\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This is conceptually the clearest answer, I think. "Messing around with power series and using Abel's theorem" is a very standard technique, and once you realize you can apply it here by using $-1/2$ in the binomial coefficient, the rest is just algebra.

Answer (score 3):

Well , imagination is the magic and you will see the best and most elegent method that follows as such:

$$1+\frac{1\cdot3}{6}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{6\cdot8}+ \cdots=1+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot(6-5)}{6}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot(8-7)}{6\cdot8}+\cdots$$
$$=1+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot6}{6}-\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{6}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot8}{6\cdot8}-\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}{6\cdot8}\cdots=1+1\cdot3=1+3=4$$

Well , this telescoping method really helps in majority of cases.:)

Comment: Why repeat earlier answer (minus a proof), one year later?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the general term after the first is

$$\frac{(2n+1)! \cdot 4 \cdot 2}{2^n \cdot n! \cdot 2^{n+2} \cdot (n+2)! } \ , $$

with $ \ n \ \ge \ 1 . $

The series then ought to be convergent.  The series is clearly larger than

$$1 \ + \  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}  \cdot \left( \ \frac{5}{8} \ \right)^n \ , $$

so the sum is bigger than 2, but not infinite.  That leaves 4 among the choices.

Answer (score 1):

A probability approach.

Let $\{C_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be independent random bits such that $P(C_n=1)=\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$.

Then $$\prod_{k=1}^{n}P(C_k=0)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2(k+1)}\right)\to 0\text{ as }n\to\infty$$

So we can define a random variable $X$ to be the least $n$ such that $C_n=1$, and you get that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(X=n) = 1,$$ since $P(X>n)\to 0$.

But a quick calculation shows:

$$P(X=n)=P(C_n=1)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}P(C_k=0)=\frac{1}{2(n+2)}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{2k+1}{2k+2} = \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot \cdots \cdot (2n-1)}{4\cdot 6\cdot \cdots \cdot 2(n+2)}$$

Now your sum is $4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X=n) = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose $a_n= \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n+1)}{6 \cdot 8 \cdots (4+2n)},\, n\ge1$.

Using Stirling's formula we can see $a_n \sim n^{-3/2}$. Then the series converges. For the other side, the series is bigger than  2.